# How to get images for foods fetched on USDA FoodData Central API?

Tags: data-request, api, data.gov, government, images

On the USDA FoodData Central API, I can successfully fetch foods, and get all of their details. However, I realized that the USDA FoodData Central API does not return an image for the foods. As per my requirements, I need an image to accompany the food.

I tried using the UPC number to fetch the image by using a barcode API, however a lot of the time it does not work and doesn't return any data. Also, this method won't work for Foundational Food types.

Also, if someone knows of a better food API which provides images, please tell me. I would be willing to switch to another API if that one has food images (as well as food names, branded and general).

Comment: Can you get me name of food items?

Comment: If you want examples of what I'm looking for, they are like apples, Doritos, tacos, Taco Bell burrito, salad, cheddar cheese, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get images for food and other items on [USDA Photos Search Engine](https://search.usa.gov/search/docs?affiliate=agriculturalresearchservicears&dc=1218&query=). Here, after searching you have to look for search result with description "News Image Number..". For example : You can see for "onion" in given images.[image: Search results for "onion".]. [image: On following mentioned search result.]I tried to automate result with web scrapping, but it is not working with well.

Comment: @undevable Please let me whether it helps or not?

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. It only works for very general foods (i.e. Onions, Cheese), but for branded foods, it does not work (i.e. Doritos). Thanks for the answer though.